# How to increase Simple T-SQL query Performance - taking long hours to complete. Please....!

Tags: sql-server, query-tuning

I have the following simple query with 2 table joins and a `WHERE` clause.

I already indexed the key joining fields as well as the `WHERE` clause field.

These 2 tables have about 123 million rows which is pretty huge. It takes about 7/8 hours to complete the full query below. I indexed and not sure what else to do since it's such a simple query with a `JOIN` & `WHERE` clauses:

```
insert into dbo.IMS_CLAIMS(CLAIM_ID
                          ,DX_CLAIM_ID
                          ,SVC_SEQ_NBR
                          ,SVC_DT
                          ,ALLWD_AMT
                          ,BILL_AMT
                          )
select h.CLAIM_ID
      ,h.DX_CLAIM_ID
      ,s.SVC_SEQ_NBR
      ,h.SVC_DT
      ,s.ALLWD_AMT
      ,s.BILL_AMT
from [2016Q4_VITALS_EXPORT_HEADERS] as h
    inner join [2016Q4_VITALS_EXPORT_SERVICE] as s
        on h.claim_id = s.claim_id
where cast(SVC_DT as date) >= '2015-10-01'
      and cast(SVC_DT as date) <= '2016-11-30';
```

Estimated Execution Plan:

[image]

Comment: What indexes are on 2016Q4_VITALS_EXPORT_SERVICE?

Comment: Why are you having to cast fields as date? How are these dates stored?

Comment: Try to avoid the table scan by creating an index on that. this saves lots of i/o because fat arrows = lots of rows. That RID Lookup can optimized with a clustered index. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2006/06/30/bookmark-lookup/

Comment: I already indexed SVC_DT & claim_id fields. SVC_DT is a varchar data type and I need to cast it to pull accurate monthly data.

Comment: Brend - thanks for the suggestion, I can try creating a clust index but it'l eat up so much space with 100+ million rows in it. It just a raw table but will investigate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
 WHERE cast(SVC_DT as date) >= '2015-10-01' And cast(SVC_DT as date) <= '2016-11-30'
```

When you cast SVC_DT to a date, you are forcing SQL Server to read every row, perform the cast, then do the comparison to '2015-10-01'.  This precludes the usage of indexes on SVC_DT.

```
 WHERE SVC_DT >= '2015=10-01'  AND SVC_DT < '2016-12-01'
```

Note that we have to bump the ending date from 11/30 to 12/01, and that the <= changed to <

The logic is the same as above, but now SQL Server can use an index.

Comment: Actually if SVC_DT is a datetime then this isn't an issue. The cast/convert from datetime to date is actually SARGable. :) http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Actually SVC_DT is varchar data type. It's a raw client data. That's the reason for casting.

Comment: @Syed this solution will work for string datatype as good as date

Comment: Mikhail Lobanov:  actually I thought about it but wasn't sure. Thanks for the tips!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have any indexes on the table: dbo.IMS_CLAIMS, drop them all.

Bulk insert on a heap is much faster, than on a table with indexes.